# CakePHP: group items and show last id instead of first

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a database table with items like:

```
| id | name  | created             | modified            |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 10 | test1 | 2014-11-27 14:05:39 | 2014-11-27 14:05:39 |
| 11 | test1 | 2014-11-28 14:05:39 | 2014-11-28 14:05:39 |
| 12 | test2 | 2014-11-28 14:05:39 | 2014-11-28 14:05:39 |
```

I want to group the items by name and only show the last ID of the grouped values. But whatever I try, the first ID is always shown. In this example I want ID's 11 and 12 as output, but items 10 and 12 are shown. Maybe this is a problem with pagination?

This is the query I am running:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 20,
    'order' => array('created' => 'DESC'),
    'group' => array('name')
);
```

But even with ASC the output stays the same...

Comment: `Group by` does not guarantee it will return other columns in proper order.

Comment: It's not really clear (to me) what you want. What is it you want exactly?

Comment: I have 3 entries, two of them have the same name. I just want to show the test1 and test2 items, but for test1 (name) the last one. So with created the 28th instead of the 27th (id = 11). It keeps returning id=10

Comment: As @Dennis asked, you should show the EXACT output you want. Edit your question, and put the expected result set in your question (formatted like the example of table records would be preferred.) The answer is either trivial or complex based on the columns you want. Do you know how to write the SQL statement that retrieve the correct results? If so, share that also.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 20,
    'order' => array('model_name.created' => 'DESC'),
    'group' => array('model_name.name')
);
```

Some time it happens because of model association. Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: It didn't make the change needed :(

Comment: Added the model names 'Content.created' and 'Content.name' to it

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to just add a virtual field?

Can do on-the-fly in the controller with something like:

```
$this->Model->virtualFields['last_id'] = 'MAX(Model.id)';
```

Here's an example:

Data table "groupers":

```
mysql> select * from groupers;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Jack |
|  2 | Jack |
|  3 | Mary |
|  4 | Kyle |
|  5 | Mary |
+----+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

GroupersController.php:

```
<?php
class GroupersController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $this->Grouper->virtualFields['last_id'] = 'MAX(Grouper.id)';
        $data = $this->Grouper->find(
            'all', 
            array(
                'group' => array('Grouper.name')
            )
        );
        $this->set('groupers', $data);
    }

}
```

$groupers output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Grouper] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Jack
                    [last_id] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Grouper] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => Kyle
                    [last_id] => 4
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Grouper] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Mary
                    [last_id] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

And the SQL generated by Cake:

```
SELECT `Grouper`.`id`, `Grouper`.`name`, (MAX(`Grouper`.`id`)) AS `Grouper__last_id` FROM `lt_events`.`groupers` AS `Grouper` WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `Grouper`.`name`
```

(Note paginate just extends find, so the functionality should not differ.)

Comment: Gives the same output

Comment: "Same" as in Model.last_id returns 10 & 12 instead of 11 & 12?

Comment: Yes... indeed it does that

Comment: Seems like there must be something missing from your example then. See the example I've added for how the virtual field can easily handle this. I think you may want to post the SQL being generated to clarify your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your paginate `$option` should like as

```
$options = array(
     'fields' => array('MAX(Model.id) as id','Model.name', 'Model.created'),
     'order' => array( 'Model.created' => 'DESC'),
     'group' => array('Model.name'),
     'limit' => 20
);
```

Then apply its paginate,

```
$this->paginate = $options;
```

Next,

```
$result = $this->paginate('Model');
```

OUTPUT :

```
| id | name  | created             | modified            |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 11 | test1 | 2014-11-28 14:05:39 | 2014-11-28 14:05:39 |
| 12 | test2 | 2014-11-28 14:05:39 | 2014-11-28 14:05:39 |
```

That's it.

Comment: Gives exactly the same output :(

Comment: Go to app/core.php turn on debug mode to 2, show me your sql.

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->paginate = array(
'limit' => 20,
'order' => array('Model.created' => 'DESC'),
'Conditions' => array (
    'Model.id' => $this->Model->find ('list', array ('fields'=> array ('DISTINCT Model.name', 'Model.id'), 'order'=>'Model.created DESC'))
);
```